# How do I get F6 on a Mac to click into the address bar on Chrome?

Tags: mac, google-chrome

On Windows I just tap F6 to do the same thing as clicking into the address bar on Chrome, on Mac it does nothing even after I make the F keys "standard function keys" in keyboard settings, but nothing I do makes F6 on the Mac keyboard do the same thing as Command+L.

I've tried going into [Apple icon] > System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts > + icon, then added Google Chrome.app and set "Jump to the address bar" as F6 (based on Google's Chrome shortcuts doc), but to no avail.

Comment: It works for me... Did you set the **Menu Title:** as `Open Location…`? Note the _ellipsis_ at the end has to be there!

Comment: Are you aware that by default the function keys on macOS are setup as media keys, to switch to function key mode you need to use the fn key.

Comment: @unknowndomain, AFAIK, by default on a wireless keyboard, F6 is not assigned and can be as the OP wants.

Comment: On Mac laptops it is the keyboard backlight brightness.

Comment: @Dave Sky, What type of Mac are you trying this on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me under macOS 10.13.5 and Google Chrome 68.0.3440.106.

Under **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts** I added Google Chrome's **Open Location…** menu command, as shown in the image below. Note the *ellipsis* at the end has to be there!

On an Apple wireless keyboard with default **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** settings, I can press **F6** when in **Google Chrome** and it does the same as the default **⌘L** does.

On a MacBook Pro with default **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** settings, I have to  press **FnF6** when in **Google Chrome** and it does the same as the default **⌘L** does.

On a MacBook Pro while changing the default **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** settings, i.e when checking **[√] Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys**, I can press **F6** when in **Google Chrome** and it does the same as the default **⌘L** does.

[image: App Shortcuts]

Comment: To clarify: it needs to include the ellipsis *character*, "…", not just three periods.

Comment: @timothymh, I already stated "Note the ellipsis at the end has to be there!", and just for the record... three periods are not an ellipsis, just three periods! :)

Comment: Right! I was clarifying what you said, since the average person probably doesn't realize there's a difference.

Comment: You're right, Command-L is from File > Open Location... which I didn't notice. Thank you.